# How to get tootip(infotip) text in python? (a popup text box appearing when a mouse cursor is hovered on)

Tags: python, windows, tooltip, pywinauto

I am currently working for an automatic screen capture program in Python3. While developing it, I ran into a couple of issues on Windows tooltip(infotip) boxes.

What I need to do is this: 
1. First I need to find out whether there is any tooltip(infotip - a small text box appearing when a mouse cursor is hovered on an icon or a button) at a specified mouse coordinates. (e.g.) When a mouse cursor is moved to (300, 300) in the main monitor and hovered for a while, does a tooltip box appear? I hope I can get the result with a boolean variable if possible. 
2. (main problem) **If there is a tooltip, how can I get the content(text) in it?**

I have tried solving the problems using pywinauto module, but as there is not much documentation about it so I am completely stucked... Can anyone help me with this? Using pywinauto module is not necessary if there is an easy way!!

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Did you read the [Getting Started Guide](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html)? It's core concept taking some time to learn. Also there is Inspect.exe mentioned in the guide. You can find that usually tooltip is a top level window or an immediate child of main form.

Comment: Thanks, but as I don't have deep understanding on Windows and I don't have much time to delve into its details for now.... Guess I need to find out another way not using tooltips.... Thanks anyway!!